# Dangling meta character in H2O keys

Tags: regex, r, macos, h2o

While trying to load a dataframe in R Studio into a local H2O instance I've got the following error:

```
tr_h2o <- as.h2o(localH2O, df)
## Error in .h2o.__remoteSend(data@h2o, .h2o.__PAGE_PARSE2, source_key = data@key,  : 
##  http://127.0.0.1:54321/2/Parse2.json  returned the following error:
##  Argument 'source_key' error: Dangling meta character '+' near index 40
##  /var/folders/oJ/oJgI4ENCErihlFUEYA4gxk+++TI/-Tmp-//RtmpjkIDBW/file2e68bf6103.csv
```

I unsderstand the problem has to do with the '+' character and the type of regular expression parsing that is performe by H2O.

Trying the same import directly on the browser for the local machine at

http://127.0.0.1:54321/2/Parse2.query

I get the same error. Somehow the instance cannot interpret correctly keys with the '+' character embbeded.

I'm workin on a OS x Machine running Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Could anyone please helpme? I've seen that some machines pad the keys with 0. Can I configure the machine to pad the H2O instance with '0's instead of '+'s?

Thank you

Comment: `Dangling meta character` Does that refer to a regex ? How is that string being used as a regex ?

Comment: I suppose uses regex to parse it's keys. The problem seems to be that in OSX the keys include the character '+' which is also a metacharacter in Regex semantics. I'vê seen some of these keys while browsing Google for a answer and it seems in other OSs the '+' is replaced by '0'. This character is a padding that is embedded in the key. The key is in fact a path to a file.